# Statistical Multiple Linear Regression Log Transformation

Tags: statistics, regression, statistical-inference

If for example we have a multiple linear regression as follows: 
$$hydrcarb=x_1+x_2tanktemp+x_3disptemp+x_4tankpres+x_5disppres+x_6tankpres^2+x_7dispres^2$$

And I am trying to do a backward elimination, I was told that in determining which variable is irrelevant/insignificant, we choose those variables which P(>|t|) is large. My question is what value is considered large? Is 0.02 large?

Also, I am supposed to transform the response variable, $hydrcarb$ to $log(hydrcarb)$, then do we log-transform the explanatory variables as well? Because if we don't, I realized that when I eliminate variables, the variables that I omit are different, which I think means that the regression model is different.

[The actual question is: Fit a multiple linear regression model with log(hydrcarb) as the response and all six explanatory variables.]

Comment: You are lucky to have a multilinear model. If to take the logarithms, you will make a awful nonlinear model. Remember that what is measured is $y$ not $\log(y)$. Moreover, backward elimination does not work with nonlinear models.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici oh. but the question asks me to. then what do i do? should i just take log of hydrcarb and leave everything as it is?

Comment: If the model is $$\log(hydrcarb)=x_1+x_2tanktemp+x_3disptemp+x_4tankpres+x_5disppres+x_6tankpres^2+x_7dispres^2$$ there is no problem. Just define $Y=\log(hydrcarb)$ an process.